# HLSL heightmap terrain normal recalculation for diffuse light

Tags: shader, hlsl, terrain, normals, heightmap

I need to apply diffuse light to heightmap based terrain, but I can't figure out how to recalculate normals.
Shader code: http://pastebin.com/S8hQm67D

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to sample nearby heights in a cross.

This code copied from here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.161.8979&rep=rep1&type=pdf

```
float3 filterNormal(float2 uv, float texelSize, float texelAspect) 
{ 
 float4 h; 
 h[0] = heightmap.Sample(bilinearSampler, uv + texelSize*float2( 0,-1)).r * texelAspect; 
 h[1] = heightmap.Sample(bilinearSampler, uv + texelSize*float2(-1, 0)).r * texelAspect; 
 h[2] = heightmap.Sample(bilinearSampler, uv + texelSize*float2( 1, 0)).r * texelAspect; 
 h[3] = heightmap.Sample(bilinearSampler, uv + texelSize*float2( 0, 1)).r * texelAspect; 

 float3 n; 
 n.z = h[0] - h[3]; 
 n.x = h[1] - h[2]; 
 n.y = 2; 

 return normalize(n); 
}
```

texelsize in your case would be (1.0f / whateverYouHeightmapResolutionIs) and texelAspect would be your "mh" value.